# Se puede generar un script a partir de una consulta en mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, mysql-workbench

Hola estoy intentando generar un script de mi base de datos pero con una consulta , sera posible hacer esto.

```
CREATE SCRIPT FROM NOMBRE_DB;
```

y a partir de esta consulta poder obtener toda la estructura de la base de datos.

Comment: No termino de entender, ¿necesitas hacer un respaldo de tu base de datos?, ¿volcar en un formato de archivo el resultado de una consulta?

Comment: puede que este material te sea útil https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706664/generate-sql-create-scripts-for-existing-tables-with-query

Comment: La liga que señala @Kevin es para SQL Server.